# Visual Basic code jumping to an apparently random location

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a Visual Basic program in Excel which opens Word documents and copies information from Word into Excel. At its heart is a for loop which goes through each table in one document. Inside the for loop is a call to a function to process that table:

```
For nCurrentTable = 1 To nTotalTable
    ' Process each table in Word document, one at a time.
    Call Process_One_Table(nCurrentTable, nTotalTable, vDocName)
Next nCurrentTable
```

The n variables are Longs, vDocName is a Variant.

Why is the script exiting that function to go to the next at the end of the for loop? It has happened at various points. Right now it occurs after (code from deep in `Process_One_Table`):

```
Cells(1, nColumn).Select
Selection.EntireColumn
```

It also occurred after I misused an assignment, assigning a String to a Long (which I've now corrected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `On Error Resume Next` in the calling procedure is the most likely cause of this. If the called procedure raises an error, execution resumes at the next line of the calling procedure.

Comment: Additionally, there would be no error handler (or an `On Error Goto 0` statement) in the *called* procedure.

Comment: @mwolfe02 Indeed, either that or the called procedure's error handler itself raises an error ;-)